# laravel custom blade directive except tag function for htmlentites output

Tags: laravel

```
\Blade::directive('specialReplace', function($expression){
    $expression = explode(',', $expression);

    $exception = $expression[0];
    $output = htmlspecialchars($expression[1]);

    if ($exception == "img") {
        $output = str_replace("&lt;img", "<img", $output);
        $output = str_replace("/&gt;", "/>", $output);
    } else {
        $output = str_replace("&lt;".$exception."&gt;", "<".$exception.">",$output);
        $output = str_replace("&lt;/".$exception."&gt;", "</".$exception.">",$output);
    }

    return "<?PHP echo $output?>";
});

@specialReplace(img, <img src=....)
```

I try to make a custom function for html out image from database without htmlentites in laravel.

My problem is I get an error `syntax error, unexpected '&'` which I have no idea

anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: provide your simple output what you want?

Comment: i want htmlentites escape img tag, so i can still out put image tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that, it should fix the error

```
return "<?PHP echo \"$output\"?>";
```

Also as an argument to your function, given the input

```
@specialReplace(img, <img src=....)
```

You'll receive an exact string you passed to the direcive (together with the brackets)

```
(img, <img src=....)
```

It doesn't look like you parse it properly.

Comment: it add \ on everything now

<img src="\&quot;https:\/\/www.google.com.tw\/images\/branding\/googlelogo\/1x\/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png\&quot;" \="">

Comment: I posted the answer too soon, take a look now ;)

Comment: ya thats why i explode string to array

Comment: the reason i do this is because i want this function also be able to escape other tag depend on what I need ex. I can choose for <b></b>

Comment: thx a lots, it really helps, im getting know where is my problem now